# EPPlus return 0 from cell with formula

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm trying to read value from sheet which contains cell with some result. This result is fetched from another sheet, for example:

[image]

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(myPath)))
{
     ExcelWorksheet output = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Results"];
     output.Cells["B2"].Calculate();
     var outval = output.Cells["B2"].Value;
}
```

But only what I receive is 0. What I'm doing wrong? How to read correct value?

Comment: can you debug and check if it reads correct formula?

Comment: also what if set `package.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;` before the calculation ?

Comment: @demo if I put breakpoint uder Formula property is empty but when I open with Excel I see that this B2 cell is pointing to other sheet Report!E4

Comment: @Renat I also did that but nothing. I'm staring believing that there is some kind of bug inside EPPlus library. Usually when I read out values from cells without formulas it's working fine but in this case I have one little bit complex Excel document with many calculations, references.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am experiencing very same problem
package.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic; didn't help at all.
I have also tried to run
                package.Workbook.Calculate();
                sheet.Cells["B4"].Calculate();
Before getting value, but I still get 0.